# Reporting Services adding users to role

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My domain account is administrator at this server, which runs sql 2008r2 and reporting service. when i navigate to "http://localhost/reports" , i can see the web ui. Anyway, i click to site settings, than navigate to Security tab. At this window i go to New Role Assignment. My problem is at this section. The only roles i see here are System Administrator and System User.

I googled about it, the screenshots i saw all had report server roles like browser,Publisher,Report builder.

Anyhow, is this about the installation process, or could it be about my domain account's permissions, or something other?

Thanks in advance

Edit

When i connect to report server using sql server management studio, in security tab i can see both roles and system roles folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles in Report Manager are contextual. What you see in site settings are System Roles, they control access to global features (content independent). Browser, Publisher etc - those are Item roles and they are assigned in context of report catalog items (folders, reports, etc) See docs for more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156034(v=sql.105).aspx 
To summarize, use SSMS is to create or update role definition, or Report Manager to assign roles to users/items